# javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.doPhase(Key key, false) OpenSSL DH Equivalent

Tags: java, openssl

I am working on OpenSSL DH key agreement. For Java, there is method

> javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.doPhase(Key key, boolean lastPhase)

if I set lastPhase = false, I can get the phase key.

But what can I do in OpenSSL ? Now I can only get the shared secret key, but not the phase Key.